# htaccess - Block a query string if not from certain domains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Any idea on how to achieve this with htaccess? Forbid an action (but allow others) if the request is not coming from allowed domains? I've tried the following but it's not working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !domain1\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !domain2\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !domain3\.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=view
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried a dozens possibilities, the above forbids the action for the domain I want to allow.

Comment: Referer should not be trusted, it may contain anything or not be set at all.